# Properties of this notion of density in $\Bbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, natural-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

For a given $S \subseteq \Bbb{N}$, the asymptotic density of $S$ is defined as

$$d_\text{asy}(S) := \lim_{n \to \infty} {\#(k \in S : k \le n) \over n}$$

If the limit exists. Wikipedia says this is also sometimes called "arithmetic density", but I want to use that phrase for a different definition of density - one which is supposed to be a measure of the proportion of arithmetic progressions contained in $S$

$$d(S) := \sup_{a \in \Bbb{N}} \left( {\#(0 \le b \lt a : a\Bbb{N} + b \subseteq S) \over a}\right)$$

Ie; for each $a$, it meaures the proportion of congruence classes modulo $a$ which are contained in $S$. I have shown a few properties of this density function:

$i)\ 0 \le d(S) \le 1$

$ii)$ if $S^c$ is finite, then $d(S) = 1$ (i.p. $d(\Bbb{N}) = 1$)

$iii)$ (trivial) if $S$ contains no infinite arithmetic progressions then $d(S) = 0$ (i.p. $d(\Bbb{N}^2) = 0$)

I want to know more about this notion of density - and especially its relation to asymptotic density (upper or lower in the case where $d_{asy}(S)$ does not exist)

Comment: Your density measure there is _very often_ going to be $0$, as many sets do not contain whole congruence classes.

Comment: Sure, sure, I know it's a very restrictive property to have d(S) > 0, let alone d(S) = 1. That's what I'm hoping for! Is there an easy neccessary/sufficient condition for when d(S) = 1?

Comment: Which function are you calling $d$ --- the first or the second? Which one is $d_{asy}$?

Comment: $d$ refers to the second definition; $d_{asy}$ refers to the first- asymptotic density. I will edit the post to make this clear

Comment: Thanks! I know that your statement (iii) is true for $d_{\mathrm{asy}}$ as well --- this is called Szemeredi's Theorem. (For finite arithmetic progressions. You can still have sets of positive asymptotic density that have no infinite arithmetic progressions.)

Comment: @Ehsaan Szemeredi's theorem states that if the Dirichlet density of a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is positive, you can find $k$ numbers which difference between any two consecutive numbers is constant for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. If you change the value of $k$, you may change the arithmetical progression. The statement $iii)$ is stronger: it states that you can find _a whole_ sequence which difference between any two consecutive terms is constant.

Comment: My main objection to your definition of density is the additivity: if you have two disjoint subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{N}$ which union is $\mathbb{N}$ and such that $d(A)=d(B)=0$, you have $1=d(A\cup B)\neq d(A)+d(B)=0$. You can build such counterexamples: Take $A=\{n:\exists k\in2\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }k^2<n<(k+1)^2\}, B=\mathbb{N}\setminus A$.

Comment: You can have $d(S)=0$ and $d_{asy}(S)=1.$ E.g, $S=\Bbb N \setminus \{a^3+b: 0\le b<a\in \Bbb N\}$.